# Can you stack the martial discipline "weretouched" in the living weapon monk subclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, combat, monk, archetype

The living weapon monk subclass has the "Martial discipline" class feature, where you can choose a martial style. And one of them say as follow:

> Weretouched. Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an unarmed attack, you can spend 1 ki point to rend your target and inflict deep bleeding wounds. At the start of each of the creature’s turns for the next minute, it takes 1d4 points of slashing damage from this effect. The effect ends early if the creature has one or more hit points restored, if any creature uses its action to expend one use of a healer’s kit, or makes a successful Wisdom (Medicine) check with a DC equal to your ki save DC.

Can you stack the bleeding effect if the enemy doesn't get rid of it?

Comment: What is the source of this subclass?

Comment: For anyone trying to look it up, this subclass is from Keith Baker's [Exploring Eberron](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/315887/Exploring-Eberron) - available on DMsguild.

Answer (score 3):

### No, as a general rule you cannot stack identical effects on a creature

The DMG explains this in chapter 8, "Running the Game", under the heading [Combining Game Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects):

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items.

A creature who is already affected by your Martial Discipline: Weretouched class feature can have the effect applied to them a second time, but they will still only take the 1d4 of damage each round. However, if the second application's duration will outlast the first, at the point the first application wears off, the second will still be in effect, and so the creature will continue taking damage.

As a note, this feature needs some editing to remove a bit of ambiguity and dubious parsing; one suspects that it is meant that the effect ends if someone uses an action to apply one use of a healer's kit *to the creature*, rather than just when anyone anywhere happens to use a healer's kit, and that the alternative option of making a medicine check should also be done as an action.